How to import JSON file (from Swagger) to Karate Labs?
currently we have API endpoint information from Swagger / Swashbuckle.
Is it possible to import Swagger JSON file into Karate Labs for automating endpoints?
Thank you in advance!
I did some research but not sure if this feature of importing a JSON file into Karate Labs is already available?

This is available as a paid feature in the IntelliJ IDE plugin.

Hi Peter,
Thanks for the response. Is there any trial or demo for this?
How about in the VS Code plugin?

@Rotchine it is planned in the VS Code plugin next year. I suggest you subscribe to the IntelliJ plugin for a month.
